# Violation of primary key constraint error when UPDATE

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following code:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
    }
    catch(Exception e)       
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("DatabasConnection Done");

    DateTime datum = DateTime.Now;
    string LastChangedBy = "System";

    foreach (Person p in myPersons)
    {
        SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand();

        try
        {
            command1 = Avreg(p.UnregistrationReason, p.GivenNameNumber, p.ProtectedIdentity, p.CitizenshipDate, connection);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("LALALALA Done");

        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonalIdentityNumber", string.Format("{0}{1}", p.PersonalIdentityNumber, p.SpecialIdentityNumber));
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", p.FirstName ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
        //command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", p.LastName ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
        //command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationCountyCode", p.NationalRegistrationCountyCode ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
        //command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode", p.NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
        //command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1", p.NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1 ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
        //command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2", p.NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2 ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
         //command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationPostCode", p.NationalRegistrationPostCode ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
         //command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationCity", p.NationalRegistrationCity ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
         //command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthCountyCode", p.BirthCountyCode ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
         //command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnregistrationDate", p.UnregistrationDate ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
         //command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthParish", p.BirthParish ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
         //command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CitizenshipCode", p.CitizenshipCode ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
         //command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CitizenshipDate", p.CitizenshipDate ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
         //command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NationalRegistrationDate", p.NationalRegistrationDate ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
         //command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ForeignDistrubtionAddress1", p.ForeignDistrubtionAddress1 ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
         //command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ForeignDistrubtionAddress2", p.ForeignDistrubtionAddress2 ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
         //command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ForeignDistrubtionAddress3", p.ForeignDistrubtionAddress3 ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
         //command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ForeignBirthCity", p.ForeignBirthCity ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());

         //command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastChangedBy", LastChangedBy);
         //command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastChangedDate", datum);

         command1.ExecuteNonQuery();

         Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}{1}", p.PersonalIdentityNumber, p.SpecialIdentityNumber));
     }
        }

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.WriteLine("Alla fält uppdaterade");

        Console.ReadKey();

             }// Put a break-point here, then mouse-over PersonalIdentityNumber...  deserializedList contains everything if you need it
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                Console.Write(" ---- FEL VID INLÄSNINGEN ------  " + e.Message);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }






        public static SqlCommand Avreg(string s, string t, string p, string c, SqlConnection connection)
        {
            try
            {


            var query = "UPDATE Seamen SET FirstName = @FirstName";//, "+
                //"LastName = @LastName, "+
                //"NationalRegistrationCountyCode = @NationalRegistrationCountyCode, "+
                //"NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode = @NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode, "+
                //"NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1 = @NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1, "+
                //"NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2 = @NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2, "+
                //"UnregistrationDate = @UnregistrationDate, "+
                //"NationalRegistrationPostCode = @NationalRegistrationPostCode, "+
                //"NationalRegistrationCity = @NationalRegistrationCity, "+
                //"BirthCountyCode = @BirthCountyCode, "+
                //"BirthParish = @BirthParish, "+
                //"CitizenshipCode = @CitizenshipCode, "+
                //"CitizenshipDate = @CitizenshipDate, " +
                //"NationalRegistrationDate = @NationalRegistrationDate, "+
                //"ForeignDistrubtionAddress1 = @ForeignDistrubtionAddress1, "+
                //"ForeignDistrubtionAddress2 = @ForeignDistrubtionAddress2, "+
                //"ForeignDistrubtionAddress3 = @ForeignDistrubtionAddress3, "+
                //"ForeignBirthCity = @ForeignBirthCity, "+
                //"LastChangedBy = @LastChangedBy, "+
                //"LastChangedDate = @LastChangedDate";

            SqlCommand command1;



            if (c == "0")
            {
                query += ", CitizenshipDate = null";
                command1 = new SqlCommand(query, connection);




            }
            else
            {
                query += ", CitizenshipDate = @CitizenshipDate";
                command1 = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CitizenshipDate", c ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());

            }


            if (p == "J")
            {

                query = "UPDATE Seamen SET FirstName ='Skyddad personuppgift'";//, " +
                //"LastName = 'Se hjälptext', " +
                //"ProtectedIdentity = '1', " +
                //"NationalRegistrationCountyCode = NULL, " +
                //"NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode = NULL, " +
                //"NationalRegistrationCoAddress = NULL, " +
                ////"NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1 = NULL, " +
                ////"NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2 = NULL, " +
                //"UnregistrationDate = NULL, " +
                //"NationalRegistrationPostCode = NULL, " +
                //"NationalRegistrationCity = NULL, " +
                //"BirthCountyCode = NULL, " +
                //"BirthParish = NULL, " +
                //"CitizenshipCode = NULL, " +
                //    //"CitizenshipDate = @CitizenshipDate, " +
                //"NationalRegistrationDate = NULL, " +
                //"ForeignDistrubtionAddress1 = NULL, " +
                //"ForeignDistrubtionAddress2 = NULL, " +
                //"ForeignDistrubtionAddress3 = NULL, " +
                //"UnregistrationReason = NULL, " +
                //"ForeignBirthCity = NULL, " +
                //"LastChangedBy = @LastChangedBy, " +
                //"GivenNameNumber = NULL, " +
                //"LastChangedDate = @LastChangedDate WHERE PersonalIdentityNumber = @PersonalIdentityNumber";



                command1 = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                command1.Parameters.Clear();
                return command1;
            }

             if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t))
            {
                query += ", UnregistrationReason = @UnregistrationReason";
                query += ", GivenNameNumber = @GivenNameNumber ";

                command1 = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnregistrationReason", s ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GivenNameNumber", t ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());

            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(t))
            {
                query += ", UnregistrationReason = @UnregistrationReason, GivenNameNumber = @GivenNameNumber WHERE PersonalIdentityNumber = @PersonalIdentityNumber";
                command1 = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

                t = "00";
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnregistrationReason", s ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GivenNameNumber", t ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());

            }

            else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t))
            {
                query += ", GivenNameNumber = @GivenNameNumber WHERE PersonalIdentityNumber = @PersonalIdentityNumber";
                command1 = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

                command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GivenNameNumber", t ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());

            }
            else
            {

                    query += ", GivenNameNumber = @GivenNameNumber WHERE PersonalIdentityNumber = @PersonalIdentityNumber";
                    t = "00";
                    command1 = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

                    command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GivenNameNumber", t ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());

                    return command1;

            }
             return command1;

        }


        catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
//}
```

The error occurs here:

```
command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PersonalIdentityNumber", string.Format("{0}{1}", p.PersonalIdentityNumber, p.SpecialIdentityNumber));
command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", p.FirstName ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());
//command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", p.LastName ?? DBNull.Value.ToString());

command1.ExecuteNonQuery();

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}{1}", p.PersonalIdentityNumber, p.SpecialIdentityNumber));
```

I get error:

> Violation of Primary key constraint 'PK_logSeamen'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.logSeamen'. The statement has been
>   terminated.

Do I need need to clear the `SqlCommand`?

Apperently I had this trigger

```
USE [Bums]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[trSeamen_LogI]    Script Date: 05/16/2016 11:43:58 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trSeamen_LogI] ON [dbo].[Seamen] AFTER INSERT AS
INSERT INTO [logSeamen] ([PersonalIdentityNumber], [ProtectedIdentity], [ReferedCivicRegistrationNumber], [UnregistrationReason], [UnregistrationDate], [MessageComputerComputer], [GivenNameNumber], [FirstName], [MiddleName], [LastName], [NotifyName], [NationalRegistrationDate], [NationalRegistrationCountyCode], [NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode], [NationalRegistrationCoAddress], [NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1], [NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2], [NationalRegistrationPostCode], [NationalRegistrationCity], [NationalRegistrationNotifyDistributionAddress], [NationalRegistrationNotifyPostCode], [NationalRegistrationNotifyCity], [ForeignDistrubtionAddress1], [ForeignDistrubtionAddress2], [ForeignDistrubtionAddress3], [ForeignDistrubtionCountry], [ForeignDate], [BirthCountyCode], [BirthParish], [ForeignBirthCity], [CitizenshipCode], [CitizenshipDate], [Email], [Telephone], [Mobiletelephone], [Gender], [NotNewsPaper], [Note], [StatusCode], [NationalRegistrationCode], [RegistrationDate], [LastUpdatedFromNavet], [TemporaryDistrubtionAddress1], [TemporaryDistrubtionAddress2], [TemporaryDistrubtionAddress3], [TemporaryDistrubtionCountry], [Password], [VisibilityLevel],[SeamanIdentity], [LastChangedBy], [LastChangedDate], LogAction)
SELECT [PersonalIdentityNumber], [ProtectedIdentity], [ReferedCivicRegistrationNumber], [UnregistrationReason], [UnregistrationDate], [MessageComputerComputer], [GivenNameNumber], [FirstName], [MiddleName], [LastName], [NotifyName], [NationalRegistrationDate], [NationalRegistrationCountyCode], [NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode], [NationalRegistrationCoAddress], [NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1], [NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2], [NationalRegistrationPostCode], [NationalRegistrationCity], [NationalRegistrationNotifyDistributionAddress], [NationalRegistrationNotifyPostCode], [NationalRegistrationNotifyCity], [ForeignDistrubtionAddress1], [ForeignDistrubtionAddress2], [ForeignDistrubtionAddress3], [ForeignDistrubtionCountry], [ForeignDate], [BirthCountyCode], [BirthParish], [ForeignBirthCity], [CitizenshipCode], [CitizenshipDate], [Email], [Telephone], [Mobiletelephone], [Gender], [NotNewsPaper], [Note], [StatusCode], [NationalRegistrationCode], [RegistrationDate], [LastUpdatedFromNavet], [TemporaryDistrubtionAddress1], [TemporaryDistrubtionAddress2], [TemporaryDistrubtionAddress3], [TemporaryDistrubtionCountry], [Password], [VisibilityLevel], [SeamanIdentity], [LastChangedBy], [LastChangedDate], 'INSERT' FROM INSERTED
```

How can I make sure it doesn't violate the primary key constraint?

UPDATE 2

```
USE [Bums]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[trSeamen_LogU]    Script Date: 05/16/2016 12:53:46 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trSeamen_LogU] ON [dbo].[Seamen] AFTER UPDATE AS
INSERT INTO [logSeamen] ([PersonalIdentityNumber], [ProtectedIdentity], [ReferedCivicRegistrationNumber], [UnregistrationReason], [UnregistrationDate], [MessageComputerComputer], [GivenNameNumber], [FirstName], [MiddleName], [LastName], [NotifyName], [NationalRegistrationDate], [NationalRegistrationCountyCode], [NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode], [NationalRegistrationCoAddress], [NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1], [NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2], [NationalRegistrationPostCode], [NationalRegistrationCity], [NationalRegistrationNotifyDistributionAddress], [NationalRegistrationNotifyPostCode], [NationalRegistrationNotifyCity], [ForeignDistrubtionAddress1], [ForeignDistrubtionAddress2], [ForeignDistrubtionAddress3], [ForeignDistrubtionCountry], [ForeignDate], [BirthCountyCode], [BirthParish], [ForeignBirthCity], [CitizenshipCode], [CitizenshipDate], [Email], [Telephone], [Mobiletelephone], [Gender], [NotNewsPaper], [Note], [StatusCode], [NationalRegistrationCode], [RegistrationDate], [LastUpdatedFromNavet], [TemporaryDistrubtionAddress1], [TemporaryDistrubtionAddress2], [TemporaryDistrubtionAddress3], [TemporaryDistrubtionCountry], [Password], [VisibilityLevel], [SeamanIdentity],[LastChangedBy], [LastChangedDate], LogAction)
SELECT [PersonalIdentityNumber], [ProtectedIdentity], [ReferedCivicRegistrationNumber], [UnregistrationReason], [UnregistrationDate], [MessageComputerComputer], [GivenNameNumber], [FirstName], [MiddleName], [LastName], [NotifyName], [NationalRegistrationDate], [NationalRegistrationCountyCode], [NationalRegistrationMunicipalityCode], [NationalRegistrationCoAddress], [NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress1], [NationalRegistrationDistributionAddress2], [NationalRegistrationPostCode], [NationalRegistrationCity], [NationalRegistrationNotifyDistributionAddress], [NationalRegistrationNotifyPostCode], [NationalRegistrationNotifyCity], [ForeignDistrubtionAddress1], [ForeignDistrubtionAddress2], [ForeignDistrubtionAddress3], [ForeignDistrubtionCountry], [ForeignDate], [BirthCountyCode], [BirthParish], [ForeignBirthCity], [CitizenshipCode], [CitizenshipDate], [Email], [Telephone], [Mobiletelephone], [Gender], [NotNewsPaper], [Note], [StatusCode], [NationalRegistrationCode], [RegistrationDate], [LastUpdatedFromNavet], [TemporaryDistrubtionAddress1], [TemporaryDistrubtionAddress2], [TemporaryDistrubtionAddress3], [TemporaryDistrubtionCountry], [Password], [VisibilityLevel], [SeamanIdentity],[LastChangedBy], [LastChangedDate], 'UPDATE' FROM INSERTED
```

Comment: is your personalidentitynumber not autoincrement?

Comment: @BugFinder No it is not. However. The code works while not including specific PersonalIdentityNumbers, which seem strange..

Comment: You also have a bug in there, when the connection fails, it will fall through and continue executing the rest of the code.

Comment: The error says you are trying to Insert while the Title of this posting says Update.  It looks like you are executing an INSERT not an UPDATE.  So it looks like you have a table with a primary key and you are trying to insert a  duplicate key.  You need to use an Update Command (not Insert).

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code only. Please read how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @jdweng I don't INSERT anywhere in my code, only UPDATE hence the title.

Comment: @t0mm13b What do you suggest instead?

Comment: But, and if you have `PersonalIdentityNumber` 11 and `SpecialIdentityNumber` 3 and then `PersonalIdentityNumber` 1 and `SpecialIdentityNumber` 13?

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: OP: Simple, log the error, bail out early, think about it, if the connection fails, why would you want to continue try a CRUD operation that requires a failed connection?

Comment: What is PK_logSeamen? On what column is it defined? What is definition of this column e.g. data type, identity or something else?

Comment: @Alex PK_logSeamen is the Primary key to the table LogSeamen. It is the PersonalIdentityNumber of the table LogSeamen that logs everything. The trigger is inserting/updating everything everytime something happens to the Seamen table.

Comment: As @Cetin Basoz said, it should be obvious now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger is inserting a series of values from Inserted table and you are saying PersonalIdentityNumber is the primary key in LogSeamen. Then it is obvious that, it would be violated on each update, because it is already inserted there on first insert operation. Remove PK_LogSeamen, or better yet create another auto generated column for the PK.

Comment: You're right, that's what I thought too at first. However the purpose of LogSeamen is to log the changes(the updates) that happened to each row. Therefore the same PersonalIdentityNumber can be inserted multiple times. If I search for specific PersonalIdentityNumber on the LogSeamen, I get multiple rows with the same PersonalIdentityNumbers because as I said, it logs the changes that happened, therefore the same PersonalIdenityNumber can be inserted multiple times in LogSeamen.

Comment: I fixed it. The problem was that sometimes, there was nothing to updated so it assumed that it was exactly the same. I included a "LastChanged" column to allow it to always update to the current time so now it will always update no matter what. Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1):

RE:

> Violation of Primary key constraint 'PK_logSeamen'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.logSeamen'. The statement has been
>   terminated.

Looks like you have an update trigger on Seamen  table. Check what your trigger is doing and fix if necessary.

Comment: Do you have a trigger only for insert or for update as well?

Answer (score 0):

Updates can happen many times on a table. Your `logSeamen` table is meant to track changes, and it is always possible that the row being updated was already updated sometime in the past. You can not mark `PersonalIdentityNumber` (or any column from `Seamen` table) as Primary Key in `logSeamen` table.

To fix the problem,

Remove primary key constraint from `PersonalIdentityNumber` column in the `logSeamen` table, so that you can insert same `PersonalIdentityNumber` multiple times.

Optionally, add a new column (say `logSeamenId`) as primary key with `INDENTITY(1,1)`, which would auto-generate a number for that row.

Comment: I fixed it. The problem was that sometimes, there was nothing to updated so it assumed that it was exactly the same. I included a "LastChanged" column to allow it to always update to the current time so now it will always update no matter what. Thank you for you help.